# Methods in C# Interfaces, Abstract classes

Tags: java, c#, interface, abstract-class

Are the methods declared in interfaces always abstract?.How do we achieve multiple inheritance using abstract class and interface. Are the implementation different to that of java?.

Comment: Yes - Interfaces are by design an abstraction. You cannot provide implementation with and interface.

Comment: Yes. In C# you can't (but in other .NET language it's possible). Just do it. yes, of course.

Comment: @AlexRumba If you want to see how my project actually use an abstract class and interface, here is the link to it: https://github.com/Sweeper777/MineTris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are the methods declared in interfaces always abstract?

Yes! C# interfaces can only contain abstract methods.

> How do we use static methods in interfaces.

I'm pretty sure that you can't declare static methods in interfaces. Even if you can, there is no point of doing so. Static methods can be called anywhere, right? So why do you want to put them in an interface? Put them in a static class instead!

> How do we achieve multiple inheritance using abstract class and interface.

We can't. C# DOES NOT support multiple inheritance. One class can inherit from one class **only** ! This is because multiple inheritance in C++ greatly increases the complexity of your code. But classes can implement multiple interfaces. We can only do *polymorphism* with them.

Btw, abstract classes are a kind of class.

> Are the implementation different to that of java

This depends on what do you mean by implementation.

If you mean the way to implement interfaces, yes, they are almost, if not all, the same*. If you mean the language implementations of interfaces, no, every language is different.

*However in C# you can explicitly implement an interface. In Java you can't.

EDIT:

After reading your comment, I know that you want an example showing a class that inherits an abstract class and an interface. Luckily, I did a project and it contains this kind of things!

I wrote a Tetris game a long time ago and here is the basic model of it.

I have a `TetrisBlock` class which represents a single Tetris block. And a `Tetrimino` class that represents a block of Tetris blocks, e.g.

```
   口
口口口
```

There are a lot of kinds of tetriminos, so `Tetrimino` is an abstract class. And classes such as `LShapedTetrimino` or `TShapedTetrimino` inherit from it.

However, some tetriminos can rotate but some can't, such as

```
口口
口口
```

So the ones that can rotate implements an interface called `IRotatable`.

```
public interface IRotatable {
    void Rotate ();
}
```

If you don't know already, interface implementations are "can be used as" or "has the ability to" relations. So in this case, some tetriminos have the ability to rotate but some don't. That's why some tetriminos implement the interface but some don't.

This all makes perfect sense, doesn't it?

"But I can just put the rotate method in the Tetrimino class, why do I need an interface for that?" You asked. Well, IMO, C# is an object oriented language, and the whole point of OOP is to make things make sense! Sometimes it's good to make your code make sense. I used to be confused by this a lot. I thought writing code is all about practical stuff. But that isn't the whole story. You also need to make things make sense. That's the whole point of OOP.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, methods declared in interface is abstract.

An interface only contains method definitions but does not contain any code. you need to implement all the methods defined in the interface.
An abstract class is a class that can not be instantiated but that can contain code.

A class may inherit from multiple interfaces. but a class may inherit from only one abstract class.

The multiple inheritance concept is mostly same in C# and Java

sample codes

```
//ABSTRACT CLASS:
public abstract class Car
{
    public abstract void Manufactured(); //abstract method
}

public class Honda : Car
{
    public override void Manufactured()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Honda is a Japanese car.");
    }
}

public class Renult : Car
{
    public override void Manufactured()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Renault is a Franch car.");
    }
}

  //INTERFACE:
public interface IBike
{
    void Manufactured();
}
public interface KBike
{
    void Model();
}


public class Suzuki : IBike , KBike // multiple inheritance using interface
{
    public void Manufactured()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Suzuki is prodused on Japan.");
    }
   public void Model()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Suzuki is prodused on Japan.");
    }

}
```

sample with both interface and abstract class

```
public interface IWork
{
void func();
}
public abstract class WorkClass,IWork
{
public void func()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Calling Abstract Class Function");
}}

public class MyClass:WorkClass{
...
}
```

Comment: I know what an interface and an abstract class is. I wanted an example description of multiple inheritance using both abstract and interface.

Comment: @AlexRumba see my edited answer

Comment: upvoted for you. Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 1):

Why you want to override a static method? it even says static...
I would generaly recommend you to read about patterns there you probably find something to solve your problem.

Comment: Btw. you can make default implementations in Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html